# password authentication failed for user "username" on docker-compose and typeorm

Tags: postgresql, docker, express, docker-compose, typeorm

Please help me. I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error, but everything I've done so far has been unsuccessful.
I am new to docker and I am new to backend development. I'm trying to set up a typeORM config using express, postgresql and docker. The problem is that I am getting this error.

```
thrupenny-bot-db-1   | 2023-03-23 00:34:54.034 UTC [28] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "botuser"
thrupenny-bot-db-1   | 2023-03-23 00:34:54.034 UTC [28] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
thrupenny-bot-app-1  | error: password authentication failed for user "botuser"
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   length: 103,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   severity: 'FATAL',
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   code: '28P01',
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   detail: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   hint: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   position: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   internalPosition: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   internalQuery: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   where: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   schema: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   table: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   column: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   dataType: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   constraint: undefined,
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   file: 'auth.c',
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   line: '326',
thrupenny-bot-app-1  |   routine: 'auth_failed'
thrupenny-bot-app-1  | }
```

please help me figure out what the problem is.
Link to the full project repository: https://github.com/almen2000/helpme

I tried different docker-compose.yml configs but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What I get for that github repo is "Error: DataSource is not set for this entity."

Comment: i got this error too, but use pgadmin can connect to pg  successfully. So I guess it should be related to the typeorm's database configuration. 